# Storage allocator out of space error on unix shell script

Tags: shell-script, memory, ksh

While running the script called abc.sh, following errors are thrown.

```
 abc.sh: line 226: storage allocator out of space on 64946176 byte request ( region 64329285632 segments 1981 busy 202:65087584:64913312 free 1983:64264004608:64880544 ) [Cannot allocate memory]
```

Line number 226 has the following

```
  226  sed 's/||/|/g' sales.txt >>sales.1.txt
  227  var_check=`awk -F '|' 'NF!=22{print $0}' sales.1.txt`
```

Please let me know what might be the issue.

PS: This is not a script generated error message and not UNIX disk space issue as the environment has 40% free space left.

Comment: we are not aware of any abc.sh, can you show us at least line 226 ? or give more context about what you are trying to do ?

Comment: edited the question, Please check

Comment: can the error be reproduce using the sed command ? or the var affectation below ? how big are sales.txt (though I don't think this is the issue).

Comment: it is a 74 MB file. I have no idea what is var affectation ? can you please elaborate on that.

Comment: According to Google 64946176 bytes = 65mb  Could you also provide the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because I was using a huge file in awk command which couldn't support huge data. I split it up in to two so that size was reduced and issue was solved.